# Connection timeout when retrieving data from drupal for gatsby

Tags: javascript, node.js, drupal, gatsby

I am using gatsby as a static site generator with drupal as the backend. The data is retrieved with the [gatsby-source-drupal](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-drupal/) plugin. My configuration for the plugin is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  //Excluded irrelevant configurations
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-drupal',
      options: {
        baseUrl: 'https://example.org',
        apiBase: 'jsonapi',
        concurrentFileRequests: 120,
        disallowedLinkTypes: [
          //Standard disallows
          'self',
          'describedby',
          //Erroneous resources
          'block--block',
          'field_storage_config--field_storage_config',
          'menu--menu'
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Now I have a strange phenomenon that I can retrieve all the data using my host machine but this fails within a docker container with the error:

```
ERROR #11321  PLUGIN
"gatsby-source-drupal" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:
connect ETIMEDOUT <Ip Address>:443
```

This failure happens for random backend collections, eliminating the possibility that a specific collection is problematic. Retrieving the failing resource within the container with `curl` is successful. I don't think that a server limit is a problem too, since the data retrieval functions on my host machine. I compared the memory usage for both node installations (v12) using `process.memoryUsage()` and got similar results.

Could there be a difference between the node process in the host machine and docker container which could be causing problems?

Answer (score 2):

I've previously run into sporadic issues with timeouts on Node when opening many parallel connections. Since you've set `concurrentFileRequests` to a rather high value, this might be the issue.

I'd recommend first trying to lower `concurrentFileRequests` to maybe 10 and seeing if the problem goes away.

If that's the case and you need higher parallelism (though I think it's unlikely you'll see much improved performance with higher values), you can try raising [`UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_uv_threadpool_size_size) and seeing if that works:

See also this issue: [NodeJS request timeouts with concurrency 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018208/nodejs-request-timeouts-with-concurrency-100)

Comment: Thanks your answer and sorry for taking so long to respond. I have since changed my work laptop (Lenovo with Ubuntu 20.04 to a Macbook Pro) and I am not experiencing the issue anymore. I am suspecting that the issue resulted from the way my docker was configured on the old device, but I have not been able to identify the difference. Do you perchance know how I can get the current value for `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE`? I have not been able to find any instructions on how to do that.